# which URL pattern is better, action/id or id/action

Tags: url, laravel-5, url-design

I would like to know which of these 2 patterns would be better:

```
/photos/123/edit
```

or

```
/photos/edit/123
```

Currently I am using the first, which gives me a `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` when I try `/photos/123/editxx` instead of a `404 not found`.

#### routes:

I am unsure where to look for the mistake, these are the `photos` routes:

```
Route::get('photos/randpics','PhotosController@randpics');
Route::get('photos/{id}/edit','PhotosController@getEdit')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::post('photos/{id}/edit','PhotosController@postEdit')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::post('photos/{id}/retag', ['as' => 'photos.retag', 'uses' => 'PhotosController@retag'])->middleware(['auth']);
Route::post('photos/{id}/delete','PhotosController@delete')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::get('photos/{id}/albums', 'PhotosController@getAlbums')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::post('photos/{id}/albums', 'PhotosController@postAlbums')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::get('photos/{id}/detail','PhotosController@detail');
Route::get('photos/{id}','PhotosController@single');
Route::post('photos/like', 'PhotosController@postLike')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::post('photos/unlike', 'PhotosController@postUnlike')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::get('photos','PhotosController@index');
```

#### getEdit() and postEdit():

The same error, complaining about an undefined variable in the master layout template appears, when I enter `/photos/123/a/a/a/` for example.

```
public function getEdit(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $pic = Pic::findOrFail($id);

    if(Gate::denies('edit-pic',$pic)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    $pic->text = htmlspecialchars($pic->text);

    $years = array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1960), range(date("Y"), 1960));

    $location = $pic->location;
    $tags = $pic->tags;
    $tagsarray = $pic->tagNames();
    $albums = $pic->albums;

    $locations = array();
    $getlocations = Location::orderBy('city')->get();
    foreach($getlocations as $gl)
    {
        $locations[$gl->id] = $gl->city.' ('.$gl->country.')';
    }

    $cats = Cat::lists('cat','cat')->all();

    return view('photos.edit',compact('pic','location','tags','tagsarray','albums','locations','cats','years'));
}


public function postEdit(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $pic = Pic::findOrFail($id);

    if(Gate::denies('edit-pic',$pic)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'    => 'max:200',
        'text'     => 'max:3000',
        'location' => 'required|exists:locations,id',
        'cat'      => 'required|exists:cats,cat',
        'jahrprod' => 'date_format:Y'
    ]);

    $pic->title = trim($request->input('title'));
    $pic->text = trim($request->input('text'));
    $pic->jahrprod = ($request->input('jahrprod')) ? $request->input('jahrprod') : null;
    $pic->location_id = $request->input('location');
    $pic->cat = $request->input('cat');
    $pic->save();

    #mail
    $maildata = array(
        'msg' => 'picture '.$id.' ( '.$request->input('title').' ) was edited by '.Auth::user()->username
    );

    Mail::send(['text' => 'emails.empty'], $maildata, function($message){
        $message->to('xx@yy.de')->from('xx@yy.de')->subject('picture edited');
    });

    return back()->with('success','photo information updated');
}
```

#### Controller.php

It seems, with more than 2 URL segments, the Controller.php is not working properly. `/domain.xy/1/2` shows the `8` but `/domain.xy/1/2/3` throws the error `Undefined variable: photos_online`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

use Auth;
use Cache;
use DB;

use App\Pic;
use App\Upload;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        dd(8);
        //.......
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking the opinionated "which practice is better" or "Why isn't the practice I chose working?"

Comment: Well, the 1st is better, but the error has nothing in common with "which url pattern is better" question

Comment: I thought there could be a 'best practice'

Comment: Like @MarcinNabiałek said, I agree the first option is the "best practice", and as that is what you're using, the error is a result of your implementation.

Comment: Can you show your getEdit and postEdit functions in your PhotoController?

Comment: You said `/photos/123/editxx` give you error but does `/photos/123/edit` works?

Comment: yes. also `/a` gives me a 404 but `/a/b/c` gives the same error. as if too many segments would be a problem with the 404 page.

Comment: See your program will give error to all odd urls or to the urls that is not mentioned in the router. So your problem is you wanna redirect all errors to 404 right?

Comment: I have a 404 error page but it does not work if the URL segment is missing. So if the route is `/trees/a/b`, `/trees/a/xxxx` will perhaps throw 404 , but `/trees/a/b/c/xxxxxx` does show a strange error about missing variables. It should say "page not found". I don't really understand what is going on.

Comment: what is the default behaviour of laravel when I enter a not defined route? like `/1/2/3/4/5` or so

Comment: What exception you exactly get? is it `NotFoundHttpException`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117728/discussion-between-haheute-and-themohammeda).

Answer (score 1):

If you follow laravel's resource controller guidelines
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

You should go with the first one.

But to fix your problem show us your route and controller function handling it.

## Update

open AppServiceProvider located in app/http/providers
and replace boot() function with this

```
public function boot()
{
    //initilizw $photos_online
    $photos_online = Cache::rememberForever('index_countpics', function() 
    { 
        return Pic::count(); 
    }); 

    #pics today 
    if (Cache::has('pics_today')){ 
        $pics_today = Cache::get('pics_today'); 
    }else{ 
        $pics_today = Pic::whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW())')->count(); 
        Cache::put('pics_today', $pics_today, Carbon::tomorrow()); 
    } 

    # count waiting uploads 
    $waiting_uploads = Cache::rememberForever('waiting_uploads', function() 
    { 
        return Upload::where('accepted',0)->where('infos',1)->count(); 
    }); 

    # user online 
    $client_ip = request()->ip(); 

    $check = DB::table('useronline')->where('ip', $client_ip)->first(); 

    $username = (Auth::guest()) ? null : Auth::user()->username; 
    $displayname = (Auth::guest()) ? null : Auth::user()->displayname; 

    if(is_null($check)){ 
        DB::table('useronline')->insert(['ip' => $client_ip, 'datum' => DB::raw('NOW()'), 'username' => $username, 'displayname' => $displayname]); 
    }else{ 
        DB::table('useronline')->where('ip', $client_ip)->update(['datum' => DB::raw('NOW()'), 'username' => $username, 'displayname' => $displayname]); 
    } 

    DB::delete('DELETE FROM useronline WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) > datum'); 

    $users_online = DB::table('useronline')->whereNotNull('username')->get(); 
    $guests_online = DB::table('useronline')->count(); 

    #unread messages 
    $unread_messages = 0; 
    if(Auth::check()){ 
        $unread_messages = Auth::user()->newThreadsCount(); 
    } 

    view()->share('photos_online',$photos_online); 
    view()->share('pics_today',$pics_today); 
    view()->share('waiting_uploads',$waiting_uploads); 
    view()->share('users_online',$users_online); 
    view()->share('guests_online',$guests_online); 
    view()->share('unread_messages',$unread_messages);
}
```